# Loading partialview in MVC using jquery ajax works in pageload but not in button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have done loading partialview to parent view using below code.

```
$('#divPartialContainer').load("./SITEUSER/Userlist?role=admin");
```

I have put this code in `document.ready(pageload)` and it's working perfectly. 
However if I put this line in a button click handler it's not calling the controller action. Please help.

```
$("#btnLoadUser").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#divPartialContainer').load("./SITEUSER/Userlist?role=admin");
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does the `#btnLoadUser` element exist in the DOM when you attach the event handler, or is it dynamically added to the DOM?

Comment: Yes, #btnLoadUser button already existed in DOM, not dynamically added one. Thanks.

Comment: In which case what you have used should work fine. Check the console for errors in the request after you click the button

Comment: XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:53269/68e07458a9354e27bd7e072c875357a1/arterySignalR/send?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAArQ2IQSLKNkil8HqYCmdzPwAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAACUsAVtvpkpJT4skhQSh1dyAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAII%2BuZoM1KxHpNLdxvDO7T4oAAAA2OfWjKwvKUH7iSCO7DAGO%2F41SFnEzl4lE%2BXsoEbMclW4Vp5pVY1ilxQAAAAMD%2Bv4kq2eUsxB9xeMGopXrEY%2FYg%3D%3D&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMYDEV%2FUSERMNGT%3FUSRID%3D217&browserName=Firefox
Line Number 1, Column 1

Comment: I don't understand this. It's in console in JS tab.

Comment: Hi Rory, Issue is resolved already.
I found that typo. ;(
Anyway thank you very much for your prompt help.
Good days ahead!